# Hyperlinks in one column, show contents in the second column?

Tags: html, hyperlink, html-table

So I have a table with two columns and one row. The left column has a list of hyperlinks. I would like the right column to display the contents of those hyperlinks when clicked.

The end result would have the left column still showing all the hyperlinks whilst the right column shows the corresponding contents. How would I go about doing this?

Here's some of the code:

```
 <body>
 <table width = "70%">
 <col width = "20%">
 <tr>
 <td><a href ="my_homepage.html"><big><strong>Home</strong></big></a>
 <br/>
 <a href ="about_myself.html"><big><strong>About myself</strong></big></a>
 <br/>
 <a href ="my_hobby.html"><big><strong>My hobby</strong></big></a>
 <br/>
 <a href ="my_Cv.html"><big><strong>My CV</strong></big></a>
 <br/>
 <a href ="my_links.html"><big><strong>Links</strong></big></a>
 </td>

 <td valign ="top"> </td>
 </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: By contents you mean what you would see if you clicked the link (e.g. what is at my_homepage.html")?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a simpler way, but I would use a fade-toggle using Javscript.

Have a div on the right with the content, which once the hyperlink is clicked will appear.

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#div").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#link").fadeToggle(1000);
        });

    });
```